# Countig points in boxes of a grid

Tags: python

assume there is a grid with some points in it just like in the plot below. 
[image: Demo]
My goal is to count the points per box of the grid. And this is my first try.

```
            for tupel in point_list:
               a=0
               b=0
               for i in self.boxvector:
                  if tupel[0] < i:
                     a=self.boxvector.index(i)-1
                     break

               for i in self.boxvector:
                  if tupel[1] < i:
                     b=self.boxvector.index(i)-1
                     break

               farray[a][b]+=1
```

It works, but it is slow. Are there to speed it a little up?

I use a variable named `boxvector` to define the grid. In this example boxvector is: `boxvector = [-1., -.5, 0, .5, 1.]`. The grid is always quadratic with maxima at -1 and 1. 
The boxes are represented through `farray`, which looks like `farray = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`. So that there is one value for each box which is incremented every time the algorithm finds a point in the corresponding box. point_list has the form `point_list = [(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(x3,y3), ...]`

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as you appear to already be using matplotlib, just use [`numpy.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html).

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
x = np.cos(3 * t)
y = np.sin(t)

gridx = np.linspace(-1, 1, 5)
gridy = np.linspace(-1, 1, 5)

grid, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=[gridx, gridy])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.grid(True)

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(gridx, gridy, grid)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: use np.arange, instead of np.linspace to get the regular grids

Answer (score 2):

See also

matplotlib.nxutils.pnpoly()

and

matplotlib.nxutils.points_inside_poly()

Very fast and efficient points inside polygons utilities. You would just have to create the polygons based on the vertices of the grid corners.

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/nxutils_api.html

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the position. divide by 0.5 (box size). Since your array starts with 0, but your coords start with -1, adjust by 1 before dividing. You'll have an edge case of 1 ( (1+1)/0.5 == 4) so make sure it won't overflow 3.

Here's an example:

```
>>> x,y = (0.8, -0.5)
>>> int((x + 1) / 0.5)
3
>>> int((y + 1) / 0.5)
1
```

Just take into account the to get the max result of 3. So:

```
>>> f_pos = lambda pos: min(int((pos + 1) / 0.5), 3)
>>> f_pos(x)
3
>>> f_pos(y)
1
```

So, bring it to completion:

```
f_pos = lambda pos: min(int((pos + 1) / 0.5), 3)
for x,y in point_list:
    f_array[f_pos(x)][f_pos(y)] += 1
```